# Problem from Halmos's Measure Theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Similar to theorem B, it's easy to show that class of all sets which may be covered by a countable
union of sets in E is a ring, but I cannot show that it's a $\sigma-ring$.

Comment: Countable union of countable union of sets from $E$ is a countable union of sets from $E$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a countable family of countable sets, if one can simultaneously choose an identification of each of the sets with $\mathbb N$, then one can show that their union will also be countable (by the "snaking" argument that shows that $\mathbb N^2$ is countable).  However, choosing such identifications simulateously requires the Axiom of Countable Choice.  Indeed, it cannot be established in ZF (without choice), since there are models of ZF where $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of countable sets (the Feferman-Levy model).

In fact, Halmos' book is sloppy about the use of the axiom of choice on other occasions, as well, as when he fails to mention that it is used in the proof of sigma-additivity of the Lebesgue measure.  On the other hand, he does mention that it is used in the "construction" of unmeasurable sets.